# Space after end=""

Tags: python, spacing

I have the lines programmed as below:

```
mystring="Phyton is totally awesome"

for q in mystring[::4]:
    print(q,end="")


mystring_2="Phyton is totally awesome"

for r in mystring_2[::4]:
    print(r,end="")
```

When run the results for mystring_2 just appends right after mystring1:

```
PostyeePostyee
```

I would like the results such that mystring2 result will be under mystring1. But I think I am missing something.

Comment: ... put a `print()` in between?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the loop, `mystring[::4]` returns a string so you can directly print it.

Also note that you do not need to define `mystring_2` if it is the same as `mystring`. Strings are immutable, so slicing returns a new one.

```
mystring="Python is totally awesome, you are right"

print(mystring[::4])
print(mystring[::4])
```

Or in an even more compact form, with a somewhat funky syntax

```
mystring = "Python is totally awesome, you are right"
print(*2*(mystring[::4],), sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just print a new line after you print mystring?
Say,

```
mystring="Phyton is totally awesome"
for q in mystring[::4]: print(q,end="")

# print a new line
print()

mystring_2="Phyton is totally awesome"
for r in mystring_2[::4]: print(r,end="")
```

Comment: Or, just remove the `end=""` part?

Comment: looks like the author want to get `Postyee\nPostyee`

Comment: Default value of `end` is `\n`. So, simply removing `end=""` will print `\n` after every `print()`

Answer (score 0):

```
mystring="Phyton is totally awesome"

for q in mystring[::4]:
    print(q,end="")

# Note :
# -----
# end = "" means avoid '\n' (newline) after printing
#

# Edited
# ------
# the below print will print only empty line.
#
print()


mystring_2="Phyton is totally awesome"

for r in mystring_2[::4]:
    print(r,end="")
```